# PHP: why does my flood prevention script lag?

Tags: php

Thank you for reading.

I have an input field that sends its contents in an XMLHttpRequest to a php script. The script queries the database with the POST data from the field and returns the results.

Because the XMLHttpRequest is invoked using onkeyup, typing in a lengthy value sends several calls in a short period. To combat this I wrote some code that creates a timestamp, loads it into the session, sleeps, then rechecks the timestamp. if the timestamp has increased, it means a subsequent call was made and the script should abort. Otherwise the script executes. Here is the code.

```
$micro = microtime(true);
$_SESSION['micro'] = $micro;
usleep(500000); // half a second
if ($micro < floatval($_SESSION['micro']))
{
    // later call has been made, abort
    echo 'abort';
    exit;
}
else
{
    // okay to execute
}
```

The code appears to work as expected at first. If I add or remove a character or two from the input field the result appears quickly.

However if I type a good 12 characters as fast as I can there is a large delay, sometimes 2 or 3 seconds long.

I am working on localhost, so there is no connection issues. The query is also really small, grabbing one column containing a single word from a specific row.

I have also set XMLHttpRequest to be asynchronous, so that should also be fine.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","/test/",true);
```

If I remove the flood prevention code, typing in the field returns results instantly - no matter how much and how quickly I type.

It's almost as if usleep() keeps stacking itself or something.

I came up with this code on my own, best I could do at my level. No idea why it isn't behaving as expected.

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried putting the `usleep(500000);` part in else?

Comment: Why don't you check the length of string typed in client side script?

Comment: You're not accomplishing a delay with php, as it is server side script. You need to delay the actual sending to the script via javascript ( or whatever client side language you're using )

Comment: Why dont you just send the data on enter? I doubt the current method would be smooth on the user

Comment: Thanks you guys .. I try to avoid using javascript wherever possible. Code examples like the one kindly provided by drew010 look scary and weird to me. And whenever I see $ in javascript I think jquery and it freaks me out. So I always try to do server side when I can. Ajax however has been amazing and I love it.

@Khaleel I do like your suggestion though of checking the length of the string. That could actually work out to be a simple solution, even if I do it in php.

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries The current method is actually pretty good, since the response doesn't change the input field in any way. Though your suggestion about detecting the enter key wouldn't be so bad.. though since the enter key isn't added to the string, I'll have to detect it client-side with javascript. Might do it if I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a session using `session_start()`, PHP locks the session file so any subsequent requests for the same session while another request has it open will be blocked until the session closes (you were exactly right with the "stacking" you suspected was happening).

You can call [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/session_write_close) to close the session and release the lock but this probably won't help in this situation.

What's happening is each time the key is pressed, a request gets issued and each one is backed up while the previous one finishes, once the session is released one of the other requests opens the session and sleeps, and this keeps happening until they've all finished.

Instead, I'd create a global variable in Javascript that indicates whether or not a request is in progress.  If one is, then don't send another request.

Something like this:

```
<script>
var requesting = false;

$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    if (requesting) return ;

    requesting = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/url"  
    }).done(function() {
        requesting = false;
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: The javascript looks a little intimidating to me, but the explanation was extremely helpful. I know what I need to do and can definitely work on a solution. Thank you ever so much! And I like the Edward :P

Comment: :) - The Javascript example is jQuery, but if you have all the XMLHttpRequest stuff you just need to put the requesting = true and requesting = false into what you already have.  Just make sure to make the variable global by declaring it outside of any function.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making a solution, though a little different. But if it wasn't for you I'd still be trying to use the session. Saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

drew010's answer explained my problem perfectly (Thanks!). But their code example, from what I gather by how it was explained (I didn't try it), does the opposite of what I need. If the user types "hello" the h will get sent but the ello might not unless the result makes it back in time. (Sorry if this was a wrong assumption)

This was the solution I came up with myself.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="textget(this.value)" />

<script>
var patience;
function ajax(query)
{
    // XMLHttpRequest etc
}

function textget(input)
{
    clearTimeout(patience);
    patience = setTimeout(function(){ajax(input)},500);
}
</script>
```

when a key is pressed in the input field, it passes its current value to the textget function.

the textget function clears an existing timer if any and starts a new one.

when the timer finishes counting down, it passes the value further to the ajax function to perform the XMLHttpRequest.

because the timer is reset every time the textget function is called, if a new call is made before the timer finishes (0.5 seconds), the previous call will be lost and is replaced by the new one.

Hope this helps someone.